# Javascript regex error, text between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])
```

which is matching text:

```
[11/Sep/2016:21:58:55 +0000]
```

it works fine in sublime while testing, but when I do

```
str.match(/(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])/)
```

Ive got error:
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: There is no lookbehind in Javascript regex

Comment: How it should look then ? Coz it works fine in editor..

Comment: Use `str.match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)` and access the first index if you need one match only.  Use `/\[([^\]]*)\]/g` with `RegExp#exec` and loop through all the matches to get all the values.

Comment: Well, editor is not using JS to evaluate. Try `/\[([^\]]*)(?=\])/` and use captured group #1

Comment: eh so tehre is no way to get text between chars ? :/ Ok I will drop first and last then ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex as :[/[^\[\]]+/](https://regex101.com/r/bAMB8W/2)

```js
const regex = /[^\[\]]+/;
const str = `[11/Sep/2016:21:58:55 +0000]`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use *capturing* and grab the Group 1 contents.

If you have one value to extract, use

```js
var m = "[11/Sep/2016:21:58:55 +0000]".match(/\[([^\]]*)]/);
console.log(m ? m[1] : "No match");
```

If there are more, use `RegExp#exec` with `/\[([^\]]*)]/g` and collect the matches:

```js
var s = "[11/Sep/2016:21:58:55 +0000] [12/Oct/2016:20:58:55 +0001]";
var rx = /\[([^\]]*)]/g;
var res = [];
while ((m=rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```